# How to edit json file resides on the remote server?

Tags: ssh, jq

I have a json file on my remote server

location at remote host : ".docker/test.josn"

{
"key1" : "Value1",
"Key2" : "Value2"
}

I want to add new element to the test.josn from my local machine. I am trying following command but it is not working.

```
ssh <test-server> "jq '.key3 = "Value3"' .docker/test.json > .docker/test2.json && mv .docker/test2.json .docker/test.json"
```

Its giving me the following error:

```
bash: .docker/test2.json: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a shell quoting issue. You didn't escape the inner double quotes.

You can try the following:

```
ssh <test-server> 'jq ".key3 = \"Value3\"" .docker/test.json > .docker/test2.json && mv .docker/test2.json .docker/test.json'
```

which replace the outer double quote with single ones because you don't need variable expansion in this statement.

Comment: @BhavikJoshi If you ssh to the server and then, using the shell,  execute the command, do you get the same error?